# Cannot retrieve ExpoPushToken on IOS

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-notifications

ExpoSDK Version - 42
Bare workflow
EAS version - 0.39.0

I have an react-native expo app build with eas build --profile preview --platform all, and on IOS i cannot seem to retrieve the ExpoPushToken. On Android it works just fine. I tried to fix the issue by removing the APN push key, the Provisioning Profile and the Distribution Certificate, and creating them again from the EAS prompts, but the problem persists.

The code I’m using for retrieving the Push token is the one from the Expo Documentation.

```
async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
  let token;
  if (Constants.isDevice) {
    const { status: existingStatus } =
      await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
    let finalStatus = existingStatus;
    if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
      const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
      finalStatus = status;
    }
    if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
      alert("Failed to get push token for push notification!");
      return;
    }
    token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();
  } else {
    alert("Must use physical device for Push Notifications");
    return;
  }

  if (Platform.OS === "android") {
    Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync("default", {
      name: "default",
      importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
      vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
      lightColor: "#FF231F7C",
    });
  }

  return token;
}
```

I’m calling this function inside a useEffect, and sending the token to the server, to store it in the users data, but on IOS the token returned is undefined.

Comment: Same problem here, did you find any solucion?

Comment: @kurtko i was missing this code from the .entitlements file
`<dict>
 <key>aps-environment</key>
 <string>development</string>
</dict>`

Comment: @gpavlov can you elaborate more? I am having the same problem but i don't have a entitlements file

Comment: @DanNeciu you need to have one, I don't remember how i created it but it looks like this 

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>aps-environment</key>
 <string>production</string>
</dict>
</plist>
`
It should be in ios -> yourprojectname folder and name it yourprojectname.entitlements

Comment: @gpavlov My project already contains the above file you mentioned. But still I am unable to get the `Device PushToken`. What else can I check?